# How can i Initialize an Array inside of a Function with the Object form as a parameter

Tags: java, arrays, function

I'm trying to make a JSONArray deserializer, but whenever the inputted Object to deserialize into is of type Array, I'm not able to figure out how to reallocate a new Array with the size of the JSONArray and set it.

I've already tried:

```java
Object[] arr = new Object[size()];
for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) arr[i] = myArrayList.get(i);
deserializedObject = arr;
```

I thought the mistake was maybe that I tried to assign an Object[] to an int[], so I changed the code to and tried it out:

```java
if (deserializedObject instanceof int[])
{
    int[] arr = new int[size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++)
    {
        Object obj = myArrayList.get(i);
        if (!(obj instanceof Number))
            throw new RuntimeException("Tried to deserialize element of type: " + obj.getClass().getName() + " into an Int Array");
        int numb = ((Number)obj).intValue();
        arr[i] = numb;
    }
    deserializedObject = arr;
}
```

now I'm thinking it's not possible...

```java
/**
* @param deserializedObject An object to deserialize into from this JsonArray
*/
public void deserialize (Object deserializedObject)
{
    Class<? extends Object> objectClass = deserializedObject.getClass();

    if (objectClass.isArray())
    {
        Object[] arr = new Object[size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) arr[i] = myArrayList.get(i);
        deserializedObject = arr;
    }
    else if (deserializedObject instanceof Collection)
    {
        Collection<Object> collection = (Collection<Object>) deserializedObject;
        collection.clear();
        for (Object o : myArrayList) collection.add(o);
    }
    else
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot deserialize to object: " + objectClass.getName() + " it is not an Array");
}
```

The expected result of this function is that all the elements inside the JSONArray will be stored into the deserializedObject parameter.
Though the output is the predefined empty Array

Comment: Can you provide the error message that you are getting when trying to execute this code?

Comment: There is no error message, though the deserializedObject won't be set to the new Object[].